# Pretty Print Hamlet output?

Tags: haskell, yesod

Im using the  following template to build some XML:

```
xml nw config = renderHtml [shamlet|
<nw version="#{version config}" nr="#{nw}">
    <compatibleHardwares>
        $forall hw <- hws
            <compatibleHardware>
                #{hw}
|]
  where
    hws = (compatiblehardware config)
```

The output is:

```
<nw version="1.0" nr="NW011"><compatibleHardwares><compatibleHardware>X4578</compatibleHardware>
</compatibleHardwares>
</nw>
```

Is it possible to pretty print the output created by hamlet ?

Comment: You mean, as actual Hamlet code, or just as properly indented html?

Comment: As properly indented html.

Comment: I'm about to go to bed so not a full answer, but it looks like [`HamletSettings`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shakespeare-2.0.7/docs/Text-Hamlet.html#t:HamletSettings) allows adding newlines to the output for readability.